# Is there a limit on what can be submitted in a JSONP request?

Tags: javascript, json, browser, jsonp

Is there a limit to how long the JSONP request can be (the src url)?

For example:

```
<script src="https://someserver.com/submit?callback=myCallback&alotofdata_maybe_5000_characters_long=true"></script>
```

Where it has a query string 5000+ characters long. Is that allowed? Will all the browsers send that? Or will some browsers cut the url off?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers)

Though the initial answer int he link above references an old article, newer tests show that most browser terminate the URL at about 3000 characters.

Avoid using a URL that you expect will be 5000+ characters in length. It cannot be guaranteed to work in all browsers.